# How can I use an http proxy with node.js http.Client?

Tags: http, proxy, node.js

I want to make an outgoing HTTP call from node.js, using the standard `http.Client`. But I cannot reach the remote server directly from my network and need to go through a proxy.

How do I tell node.js to use the proxy?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Node.js is behind a firewall and I am unable to create an HTTPClient to an external website.

Comment: You can use axios for this purpose. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74159839/9181544)

Answer (score 173, accepted):

[Tim Macfarlane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416032/tim-macfarlane)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862813/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-with-node-js-http-client/5810547#5810547) was close with regards to using a HTTP proxy.

Using a HTTP proxy (for non secure requests) is very simple. You connect to the proxy and make the request normally except that the path part includes the full url and the host header is set to the host you want to connect to.
Tim was very close with his answer but he missed setting the host header properly.

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
  host: "proxy",
  port: 8080,
  path: "http://www.google.com",
  headers: {
    Host: "www.google.com"
  }
};
http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log(res);
  res.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

For the record his answer does work with http://nodejs.org/ but that's because their server doesn't care the host header is incorrect.

Comment: Is there a way to use http proxy connect https port? seems has no easy method

Comment: @Gohan See Chris's answer below for an example on how to connect to an https server through and http proxy.

Comment: if you get bad request, put path: '/'

Comment: How can I integrate proxy-user and proxy-password in the options block?

Comment: Has this changed? Even with the final destination as another local server, I get a `404`, and the destination server never receives the request..

Comment: How can this be achieved on a global level? I'am able to do this on single requests but I have `vendor` modules which I also need to use the proxy connection.

Comment: I am getting this error with above code Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy proxy:8080

Comment: Even without using a proxy, this doesn't work. I don't think the "path" field can be used this way, I get a connection refused error with `options = { path: "http://www.example.com/", method: "GET", headers: {Host: "www.example.com"}}`.

Comment: @Samuel hi can you look my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53593182/client-network-socket-disconnected-before-secure-tls-connection-was-established ? I can't make your solution work.

Comment: If I'm not familiar with the Node.js framework, could you please tell me where exactly to put this snippet?
What if my application is running through sails.js ?
Thanks

Answer (score 71):

**EDIT**: *As of Feb 11th 2020, request is fully deprecated. No new changes are expected.*

You can use [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request),
I just found it's unbelievably easy to use proxy on node.js, just with one external "proxy" parameter, even more it supports HTTPS through a http proxy.

```
var request = require('request');

request({
  'url':'https://anysite.you.want/sub/sub',
  'method': "GET",
  'proxy':'http://yourproxy:8087'
},function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
})
```

Comment: Worked for both `http` and `https` in my case, Thanks a lot

Comment: any ideas why this won't work for internal corp pages?

Comment: I'm surprised internal corp pages are behind a proxy. Are you sure that the proxy is not being bypassed for internal pages? Is it on a different vlan?

Comment: U need to specify authentication somehow (gonna post it here if I figure it out)

Comment: I got this error using request with proxy: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

Comment: @IgorL. I got it to work with Auth and the Request Module, with `headers: {'Proxy-Authorization': XXXX}`

Comment: If the proxy is not HTTPS, isn't this insecure (password in cleartext)?

Answer (score 40):

One thing that took me a while to figure out, use 'http' to access the proxy, even if you're trying to proxy through to a https server. This works for me using Charles (osx protocol analyser):

```
var http = require('http');

http.get ({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8888,
    path: 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken'
}, function (response) {
    console.log (response);
});
```

Comment: Above code is not working for me, and its related to issue https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2474 check koichik's answer we have to use "method":"connect" and on "connect" event, we have send path information.

Answer (score 31):

I bought private proxy server, after purchase I got:

```
255.255.255.255 // IP address of proxy server
99999 // port of proxy server
username // authentication username of proxy server
password // authentication password of proxy server
```

And I wanted to use it. [First answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6781592/5431545) and [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933899/5431545) worked only for http(proxy) -> http(destination), however I wanted http(proxy) -> https(destination).

And for https destination it would be better to use [HTTP tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel) directly.
I found solution [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/2474#issuecomment-3481078).

**Node v8:**

```
const http = require('http')
const https = require('https')
const username = 'username'
const password = 'password'
const auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64')

http.request({
  host: '255.255.255.255', // IP address of proxy server
  port: 99999, // port of proxy server
  method: 'CONNECT',
  path: 'kinopoisk.ru:443', // some destination, add 443 port for https!
  headers: {
    'Proxy-Authorization': auth
  },
}).on('connect', (res, socket) => {
  if (res.statusCode === 200) { // connected to proxy server
    https.get({
      host: 'www.kinopoisk.ru',
      socket: socket,    // using a tunnel
      agent: false,      // cannot use a default agent
      path: '/your/url'  // specify path to get from server
    }, (res) => {
      let chunks = []
      res.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk))
      res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('DONE', Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8'))
      })
    })
  }
}).on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('error', err)
}).end()
```

**Node v14:**

```
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const username = 'username';
const password = 'password';
const auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');

http.request({
  host: '255.255.255.255', // IP address of proxy server
  port: 99999, // port of proxy server
  method: 'CONNECT',
  path: 'kinopoisk.ru:443', // some destination, add 443 port for https!
  headers: {
    'Proxy-Authorization': auth
  },
}).on('connect', (res, socket) => {
  if (res.statusCode === 200) { // connected to proxy server
    const agent = new https.Agent({ socket });
    https.get({
      host: 'www.kinopoisk.ru',
      path: '/',
      agent,      // cannot use a default agent
    }, (res) => {
      let chunks = []
      res.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk))
      res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('DONE', Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8'))
      })
    })
  }
}).on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('error', err)
}).end();
```

Comment: The `socket` property isn't documented in nodejs. Was this option removed.

Comment: The described approach won't work nowadays. `socket` option is not supported in `http` modules' `get` / `request` functions and simply gets ignored.

Comment: So what now? What should we use now?

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg The answer was updated to use an `Agent` with the socket specified.

Comment: The `socket` property only works in HTTPS requests, because you can specify a socket when create a tls socket. See the `tls.connect()` [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tlsconnectoptions-callback).

Comment: I receive 502 status in "on connect" callback. So the solution doesn't work for me

Comment: I had to change the 'Proxy-Authorization' header to lowercase ('proxy-authorization')

Answer (score 16):

As @Renat here already mentioned, proxied HTTP traffic comes in pretty normal HTTP requests. Make the request against the proxy, passing the **full URL** of the destination as the path.

```
var http = require ('http');

http.get ({
    host: 'my.proxy.com',
    port: 8080,
    path: 'http://nodejs.org/'
}, function (response) {
    console.log (response);
});
```

Comment: This seems to work though Fiddler calls it a protocol violation which suggests it's not a proper HTTP request-via-proxy...

Answer (score 13):

Thought I would add this module I found: https://www.npmjs.org/package/global-tunnel, which worked great for me (Worked immediately with all my code and third party modules with only the code below).

```
require('global-tunnel').initialize({
  host: '10.0.0.10',
  port: 8080
});
```

Do this once, and all http (and https) in your application goes through the proxy.

Alternately, calling

```
require('global-tunnel').initialize();
```

Will use the `http_proxy` environment variable

Comment: This worked for me! Actually this way you decouple the proxy from the code and use the existing configuration for npm! that is the way to go I would say

Comment: @NeelBasu Yes it does

Comment: As soon as I use this, the applications requests don't work anymore:
sign in failed with error RequestError: Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "undefined"

Answer (score 8):

The 'request' http package seems to have this feature:

https://github.com/mikeal/request

For example, the 'r' request object below uses localproxy to access its requests:

```
var r = request.defaults({'proxy':'http://localproxy.com'})

http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
  if (req.url === '/doodle.png') {
    r.get('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(resp)
  }
})
```

Unfortunately there are no "global" defaults so that users of libs that use this cannot amend the proxy unless the lib pass through http options...

HTH, Chris

Comment: the request http package makes it easier to allow your code to toggle between proxy and non proxy usage (which is quite useful on my laptop).

Answer (score 6):

In case you need to the use basic authorisation for your proxy provider, just use the following:

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
    host:       FarmerAdapter.PROXY_HOST,
    port:       FarmerAdapter.PROXY_PORT,
    path:       requestedUrl,
    headers:    {
        'Proxy-Authorization':  'Basic ' + new Buffer(FarmerAdapter.PROXY_USER + ':' + FarmerAdapter.PROXY_PASS).toString('base64')
    }
};

var request = http.request(options, function(response) {
    var chunks = [];
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
        console.log('Response', Buffer.concat(chunks).toString());
    });
});

request.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
});

request.end();
```

Comment: where can i find "FarmerAdapter"?

Answer (score 5):

Basically you don't need an explicit proxy support. Proxy protocol is pretty simple and based on the normal HTTP protocol. You just need to use your proxy host and port when connecting with HTTPClient. Example (from node.js docs):

```
var http = require('http');
var google = http.createClient(3128, 'your.proxy.host');
var request = google.request('GET', '/',
  {'host': 'www.google.com'});
request.end();
...
```

So basically you connect to your proxy but do a request to "http://www.google.com".

Comment: http.createClient is deprecated, Tim Macfarlane is using the newer http.get below

Comment: This will apparently no longer work with node.js as of v5.6 as they have removed [createClient](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.6/api/http.html#http.ClientResponse).

Answer (score 4):

Node should support using the http_proxy environmental variable - so it is cross platform and works on system settings rather than requiring a per-application configuration.

Using the provided solutions, I would recommend the following:

**Coffeescript**

```
get_url = (url, response) ->
  if process.env.http_proxy?
    match = process.env.http_proxy.match /^(http:\/\/)?([^:\/]+)(:([0-9]+))?/i
    if match
      http.get { host: match[2], port: (if match[4]? then match[4] else 80), path: url }, response
      return
  http.get url, response
```

**Javascript**

```
get_url = function(url, response) {
  var match;
  if (process.env.http_proxy != null) {
    match = process.env.http_proxy.match(/^(http:\/\/)?([^:\/]+)(:([0-9]+))?/i);
    if (match) {
      http.get({
        host: match[2],
        port: (match[4] != null ? match[4] : 80),
        path: url
      }, response);
      return;
    }
  }
  return http.get(url, response);
};
```

**Usage**
To use the method, effectively just replace http.get, for instance the following writes the index page of google to a file called test.htm:

```
file = fs.createWriteStream path.resolve(__dirname, "test.htm")
get_url "http://www.google.com.au/", (response) ->
  response.pipe file
  response.on "end", ->
    console.log "complete"
```

Comment: Setting http_proxy doesn't appear to have any effect when running Node on Windows.

Comment: It should work under Windows (that is the primary system I'm using). Make sure after you have set the setting that you have reset your terminal session (if set through control panel and not set). You should be able to check it's set correctly using
echo %HTTP_PROXY%

Or even better you should use node itself
node -e "console.log(process.env.http_proxy);"

This worked for me under Windows, so good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I think there a better alternative to the answers as of 2019. We can use the `global-tunnel-ng` package to initialize proxy and not pollute the `http` or `https` based code everywhere. So first install `global-tunnel-ng` package:

```
npm install global-tunnel-ng
```

Then change your implementations to initialize proxy if needed as:

```
const globalTunnel = require('global-tunnel-ng');

globalTunnel.initialize({
  host: 'proxy.host.name.or.ip',
  port: 8080
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use 'https-proxy-agent' like this

```
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
var proxy = process.env.https_proxy || 'other proxy address';
var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxy);

options = {
    //...
    agent : agent
}

https.get(options, (res)=>{...});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just run nodejs with proxy wrapper like `tsocks tsocks node myscript.js`

Original solution:
[Doing http requests through a SOCKS5 proxy in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530159/doing-http-requests-through-a-socks5-proxy-in-nodejs)

More info:
https://www.binarytides.com/proxify-applications-with-tsocks-and-proxychains-on-ubuntu/

For windows:
https://superuser.com/questions/319516/how-to-force-any-program-to-use-socks

Answer (score 1):

May not be the exact one-liner you were hoping for but you could have a look at http://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy as that may shed some light on how you can use your app with http.Client.

Comment: How is this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/d5aadbcaa00c3f7/12ebf01d7ec415c3?lnk=gst&q=proxy#12ebf01d7ec415c3

Based on the answers from this thread it would seem like you could use [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/) 
to run node.js through the proxy server:
`$ proxychains /path/to/node application.js`

Personally I wasnt able to install any of the **proxychains** versions on **Cygwin/Windows** environment so couldn't test it.

Furthermore, they also talked about using **connect-proxy** but I could not find any documentation on how to do this.

In short, I'm still stuck, but maybe someone can use this info to find a suitable work-around.

Comment: update: after some investigating found out that I could not build proxychains on CygWin because RTLD_NEXT is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Imskull's answer almost worked for me, but I had to make some changes. The only real change is adding username, password, and setting rejectUnauthorized to false. I couldn't comment so I put this in an answer.

If you run the code it'll get you the titles of the current stories on Hacker News, per this tutorial: http://smalljs.org/package-managers/npm/

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');

request({
    'url': 'https://news.ycombinator.com/',
    'proxy': 'http://Username:Password@YourProxy:Port/',
    'rejectUnauthorized': false
}, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        if (response.body) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(response.body);
            $('td.title a').each(function() {
                console.log($(this).text());
            });
       }
    } else {
        console.log('Error or status not equal 200.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Only set the environment variable and the `http` will use proxy.

```
const env = {
    "host": "proxy.server.com.br",
    "port": 8080,
    "user": "my-user",
    "pass": "my-pass"
};

process.env.http_proxy =
  process.env.https_proxy =
    `http://${env.user}:${env.pass}@${env.host}:${env.port}/`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Axios has proxy option in its [documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config).
Also you can define `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables

```js
// `proxy` defines the hostname, port, and protocol of the proxy server.
// You can also define your proxy using the conventional `http_proxy` and
// `https_proxy` environment variables. If you are using environment variables
// for your proxy configuration, you can also define a `no_proxy` environment
// variable as a comma-separated list of domains that should not be proxied.
// Use `false` to disable proxies, ignoring environment variables.
// `auth` indicates that HTTP Basic auth should be used to connect to the proxy, and
// supplies credentials.
// This will set an `Proxy-Authorization` header, overwriting any existing
// `Proxy-Authorization` custom headers you have set using `headers`.
// If the proxy server uses HTTPS, then you must set the protocol to `https`. 

proxy: {
  protocol: 'https',
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9000,
  auth: {
    username: 'mikeymike',
    password: 'rapunz3l'
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [**Basic** http authentication scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Authentication_schemes#Authentication_schemes) you have to make a base64 string of `myuser:mypassword`, and then add "Basic" in the beginning. That's the value of [Proxy-Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Proxy-Authorization) header, here an example:

```
var Http = require('http');

var req = Http.request({
    host: 'myproxy.com.zx',
    port: 8080,
    headers:{"Proxy-Authorization": "Basic bXl1c2VyOm15cGFzc3dvcmQ="},
    method: 'GET',
    path: 'http://www.google.com/'
    }, function (res) {
        res.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
});

req.end();
```

In nodejs you could use [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings) to encode

```
var encodedData = Buffer.from('myuser:mypassword').toString('base64');

console.log(encodedData);
```

Just as example, in browsers you could encode in base64 using [btoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa), useful in ajax requests in a browser without proxy settings performing a request using proxy.

```js
var encodedData = btoa('myuser:mypassword')

console.log(encodedData);
```

**How to find wich scheme accepts the proxy server?**

If we don't have a custom DNS configured (that would throw something like ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED), when we perform a request, the response (code 407) should inform in the response headers which http authentication scheme the proxy is using.