# How to use http.client in Node.js if there is basic authorization

Tags: node.js, basic-authentication

As per title, how do I do that?

Here is my code:

```
var http = require('http');

// to access this url I need to put basic auth.
var client = http.createClient(80, 'www.example.com');

var request = client.request('GET', '/', {
    'host': 'www.example.com'
});
request.end();
request.on('response', function (response) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
  response.setEncoding('utf8');
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});
```

Comment: http.createClient is deprecated. Use 'http.request' instead.

Answer (score 313):

You have to set the `Authorization` field in the header.

It contains the authentication type `Basic` in this case and the `username:password` combination which gets encoded in Base64:

```
var username = 'Test';
var password = '123';
var auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');
// new Buffer() is deprecated from v6

// auth is: 'Basic VGVzdDoxMjM='

var header = {'Host': 'www.example.com', 'Authorization': auth};
var request = client.request('GET', '/', header);
```

Answer (score 69):

From [Node.js http.request API Docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) 
you could use something similar to

```
var http = require('http');

var request = http.request({'hostname': 'www.example.com',
                            'auth': 'user:password'
                           }, 
                           function (response) {
                             console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
                             console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
                             response.setEncoding('utf8');
                             response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                               console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
                             });
                           });
request.end();
```

Comment: This is the modern-day answer.

Comment: Do you need to do "user:password" or "Basic user:password"?

Comment: @kayvar No you don't need to prefix it with Basic.

Comment: @MarceloFilho This is what I see on the docs still

auth <string> Basic authentication i.e. 'user:password' to compute an Authorization header.

Answer (score 20):

```
var username = "Ali";
var password = "123";
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");
var request = require('request');
var url = "http://localhost:5647/contact/session/";

request.get( {
    url : url,
    headers : {
        "Authorization" : auth
    }
  }, function(error, response, body) {
      console.log('body : ', body);
  } );
```

Comment: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead

Comment: Buffer.from(options.auth.user + ":" + options.auth.password).toString('base64')

Answer (score 11):

An easier solution is to use the user:pass@host format directly in the URL.

Using the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library:

```
var request = require('request'),
    username = "john",
    password = "1234",
    url = "http://" + username + ":" + password + "@www.example.com";

request(
    {
        url : url
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        // Do more stuff with 'body' here
    }
);
```

I've written a little [blogpost](http://www.haykranen.nl/2011/06/21/basic-http-authentication-in-node-js-using-the-request-module/) about this as well.

Comment: This is not ideal advice: any logging of URLs on either the client or server side could expose password values - this is a widely known security attack vector.  I strongly recommend that no-one do this. Header values are better, and not using Basic authentication - in favor of Digest authentication or OAuth 1.0a (for example) is even better.  This form of identification has also been deprecated in URIs in RFC 3986.

Comment: Not using Basic Auth sounds like some bad advice.  Basic auth requires transport security or it is completely insecure, yes.  But basic auth with transport security is way more secure that Digest authentication.  And OAuth 1 is a completely different beast with completely orthogonal security issues.

Comment: @LesHazlewood It is not fair to say compromised clients can expose passwords. Compromised client simply means all bets are off. However, your deprecation warning is fair.

Answer (score 9):

for what it's worth I'm using node.js 0.6.7 on OSX and I couldn't get 'Authorization':auth to work with our proxy, it needed to be set to 'Proxy-Authorization':auth
my test code is:

```
var http = require("http");
var auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer("username:password").toString('base64');
var options = {
    host: 'proxyserver',
    port: 80,
    method:"GET",
    path: 'http://www.google.com',
    headers:{
        "Proxy-Authorization": auth,
        Host: "www.google.com"
    } 
};
http.get(options, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    res.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

Comment: For the edification of future readers:
Thats because you are authenticating with your proxy server instead of authenticating with destination webserver (google). If you had needed to authenticate with the destination server then the Authorization header would be what you want to use.

Comment: Yes but often you need to do both so this is a solid answer

Comment: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead

Answer (score 6):

```
var http = require("http");
var url = "http://api.example.com/api/v1/?param1=1&param2=2";

var options = {
    host: "http://api.example.com",
    port: 80,
    method: "GET",
    path: url,//I don't know for some reason i have to use full url as a path
    auth: username + ':' + password
};

http.get(options, function(rs) {
    var result = "";
    rs.on('data', function(data) {
        result += data;
    });
    rs.on('end', function() {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this recently.
Which among *Proxy-Authorization* and *Authorization* headers to set depends on the server the client is talking to.
If it is a Webserver, you need to set *Authorization* and if it a proxy, you have to set the *Proxy-Authorization* header

Answer (score 2):

This code works in my case, after a lot of research. You will require to install the [request npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

```
var url = "http://api.example.com/api/v1/?param1=1&param2=2";
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");
exports.checkApi = function (req, res) {
    // do the GET request
    request.get({
        url: url,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": auth
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if(error)
       { console.error("Error while communication with api and ERROR is :  " + error);
       res.send(error);
    }
        console.log('body : ', body);
        res.send(body);      

    });    
}
```

Comment: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead

Answer (score 0):

For those not using DNS and needs more depth (you can also use `request` instead of `get` by simply replacing `get` with `request` like so: `http.request({ ... })`):

```
http.get({ 
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 443,
    path: '/books?author=spongebob',
    auth: 'user:p@ssword#'
 }, resp => {
    let data;

    resp.on('data', chunk => {
        data += chunk;
    });

    resp.on('end', () => console.log(data));
}).on('error', err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not well documented in Node.js, but you can use

```
require("http").get(
    {
      url: "www.example.com",
      username: "username",
      password: "mysecret",
    },
    (resp) => {
      let data;
      resp.on("data", (chunk) => (data += chunk));
      resp.on("end", () => console.log(data));
    }
  )
  .on("error", (err) => console.log(err));
```

Since the [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) pacakge inherits it's options object from http.request, `username` and `password` is also available there.