# How to attach files to POST request to Mailgun's API using Node.js and the Request library

Tags: node.js, request, mailgun

I'm writing some code to send emails with attachments through the [Mailgun email service](http://mailgun.net). They give the following example in their [API docs using CURL](http://documentation.mailgun.net/user_manual.html#sending-messages) and I need to figure out how to do the same thing in Node.js (preferably using the Request library).

```
curl -s -k --user api:key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0 \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v2/samples.mailgun.org/messages \
    -F from='Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>' \
    -F to='obukhov.sergey.nickolayevich@yandex.ru' \
    -F cc='sergeyo@profista.com' \
    -F bcc='serobnic@mail.ru' \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!' \
    -F html='\<html\>HTML version of the body\<\html>' \
    -F attachment=@files/cartman.jpg \
    -F attachment=@files/cartman.png
```

My current code (Coffescript) looks like the following:

```
r = request(
  url: mailgun_uri
  method: 'POST'
  headers:
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  body: email
  (error, response, body) ->
    console.log response.statusCode
    console.log body
)
form = r.form()
for attachment in attachments
  form.append('attachment', fs.createReadStream(attachment.path))
```

Answer (score 6):

For the basic authorization part you have to set the right headers and send username and password base64 encoded. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905126/how-to-use-http-client-in-node-js-if-there-is-basic-authorization) for more information. You can use the `headers` option for this.

How to send a POST request with form fields is described in the [request docs](https://github.com/mikeal/request#forms):

```
var r = request.post('http://service.com/upload')
var form = r.form()
form.append('from', 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>') // taken from your code
form.append('my_buffer', new Buffer([1, 2, 3]))
form.append('my_file', fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'doodle.png')) // for your cartman files
form.append('remote_file', request('http://google.com/doodle.png'))
```

There also some existing modules on npm that support mailgun, like

- [node-mailgun](https://github.com/shz/node-mailgun)
- [nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer) (awesome module!)

an example for nodemailer would be

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "Mailgun", // sets automatically host, port and connection security settings
    auth: {
        user: "api",
        pass: "key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0"
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: "me@tr.ee",
  to: "me@tr.ee",
  subject: "Hello world!",
  text: "Plaintext body",
  attachments: [
    {   // file on disk as an attachment
        fileName: "text3.txt",
        filePath: "/path/to/file.txt" // stream this file
    },
    {   // stream as an attachment
        fileName: "text4.txt",
        streamSource: fs.createReadStream("file.txt")
    },
  ]
}

transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, res) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log('done');
});
```

Haven't tested it because I don't have a mailgun account but it should work.

Comment: I followed the above pattern for appending the files and Mailgun sent back an error saying the "'from' parameter is missing" which made me assume I'm doing something wrong. node-mailgun doesn't support attachments (or html emails for that matter...) I hadn't thought about using nodemailer. It does support attachments and Mailgun although through the SMTP gateway, which is fine, but I'm still curious how

Comment: did you add your authorization params like `url = "https://api:key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0@api.mailgun.net/v2/samples.mailgun.org/log";` to the `mailgun_uri`? I added some code for nodemailer in my answer.

Comment: Yeah -- I didn't show all my code. I'll give nodemailer a whirl later.