# is it possible to make an authenticated request to a domain in node.js?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express, httprequest

I'm using node.js with the request.js module to make authenticated https requests like so.

```
username = req.body.username;
password = req.body.password;
var url = 'https://' + username + ':' + password + '@domain.com';
request({
    url : url,
}, function (error, response, body){
  //do something here
});
```

Is there another way to do this without having the node.js server make this call without exposing the password in plain text?

For example, say I went to http://domain.com and logged in with my credentials. I can then close my browser, revisit http://domain.com and be automagically logged in. Can I then visit my node.js app (localhost:3000) and make subsequent requests using the node app without explicitly reentering my password?

Answer (score 0):

No,  you cannot use the cookies from your browser to login with node.  But you can authenticate with node like this: [How to use http.client in Node.js if there is basic authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905126/how-to-use-http-client-in-node-js-if-there-is-basic-authorization)