# NodeJS - How to Download file via Request?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, download, request

I have a ExternalServe (running on Localhost)
When I using Browser to request:

> localhost:2013/ExternalServer/getfilebyname?filename=getStatus.json

Then browser downloaded getStatus.json to Download Folder.

In my NodeJS project, I want to download getStatus.json file and I made:

download.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

function getFile (){

  var file = fs.createWriteStream("./../lib/user.json");
  var req = http.get("http://localhost:2013/ExternalServer/getfilebyname?filename=getStatus.json", function(res) {
    res.pipe(file);
});
}

getFile();
```

but when i run: node download.js the system return

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.0-RC1 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 401 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>This request requires HTTP authentication.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.0-RC1</h3></body></html>
```

How to fix it?

Best regard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting the following error response:

> This request requires HTTP authentication

Suggesting to add the Authorization information in header. Like:

```
var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 2013,
    path: '/ExternalServer/getfilebyname?filename=getStatus.json',
    headers: {
     'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(uname + ':' + pword).toString('base64')
   }         
};

request = http.get(options, function(res) {
   res.pipe(file);
});
```

in case of proxy, you can use the following header instead:

```
Proxy-Authorization
```

Comment: if my account and password both are "tomcat", then 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer("tomcat" + ':' + "tomcat).toString('base64') ?

Comment: Thansk U very much, successed... :D

Comment: Successed, but: after save, system return a file: [object Object] at root folder.... i can't fix it..

Answer (score 0):

The server wants a username and password, or requires another authorization mechanism, before it will let you access the file this way.

To see how to supply a user and password when making the request in node.js, look at [How to use http.client in Node.js if there is basic authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905126/how-to-use-http-client-in-node-js-if-there-is-basic-authorization)

How do we know this could be the problem?

Two interesting strings in the system return:

`HTTP Status 401`

and

`This request requires HTTP authentication`

From [Wikipedia: List of HTTP Status Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

> 401 Unauthorized Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use
>   when authentication is required and has failed or has not yet been
>   provided.[2] The response must include a WWW-Authenticate header field
>   containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. See Basic
>   access authentication and Digest access authentication.

Another possibility is that a server could be set up to emit 401 instead of 403, but doesn't really accept any usernames or passwords.