# get page data from html page using node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js

Am trying to get some text from an html page using nodejs

here is the url. from this url i want to get the string `0e783d248f0e27408d3a6c043f44f337c54235ce .`
  i tried this way .but not getting any data

```
var getGitKey = function (context, callback) {
  http.get("gggg/status", function(res) {
      var data = "";
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
      });
      res.on("end", function() {
console.log("DATA-------------------------------");
console.log(data);
        callback(data);
      });
    }).on("error", function() {
     // callback(null);
    });

};
```

Please help whats wrong with my code

Comment: where do you invoke the anonymous function?

Comment: i didnt get waht u menat/

Comment: I have explained it below in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code is fine. You just need to make sure that.

1. `http` module is required with `var http = require('http');`
2. also the anonymous function you have defined and assigned to the variable `getGitKey` is never invoked. like `getGitKey();`

the complete code which worked for me is

```
var http = require("http");
var getGitKey = function (context, callback) {
http.get("http://integration.twosmiles.com/status", function(res) {
    var data = "";
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on("end", function() {
        console.log("DATA-------------------------------");
        console.log(data);
        callback(data);
    });
}).on("error", function() {
    // callback(null);
});

};
getGitKey();
```

The result was `access denied` as your page is protected with simple authentication. Same happens if you try to open it on your browser directly also. If you have a username and password to access the page, then you can refer the below SO answer for detail on using http module with basic authentication.

[How to use http.client in Node.js if there is basic authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905126/how-to-use-http-client-in-node-js-if-there-is-basic-authorization)

Comment: yes but data prints nothing.and here is no password acces in my page

Comment: from my system the url u given is protected by authentication. So for me data was `HTTP Basic: Access denied.`.  What exactly are u getting as output. do u get the initial `DATA-----` you are giving in `end` event?