# How to Make request to third-party api from node.js and express.js with 'Authorization: Basic' header

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am trying to make use of UDEMY API. Each request must contain **Authorization: Basic + keys** header.  This is in the api documentation:

`curl --user {YOUR_CLIENT_ID}:{YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET} https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/`

`curl -H "Authorization: Basic {BASE64_ENCODED(CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET)}" https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/`

This is what I have tried below but I have been getting errors.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const config = require('../config');


const { app: { API_URL, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET } } = config;


var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'courses',
    baseURL: API_URL,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + CLIENT_ID + ':' + CLIENT_SECRET,
    },
    responseType: 'json',
  };

//  Get all Posts handler
exports.getCourses = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios(options);
        console.log(response);
        res.status(200).json({ courses: response });

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({message: 'ERROR: Error Occured!'});
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/courses 500 (Internal Server Error)
ERROR Error: Error Code: 500,  Message: Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/api/courses: 500 Internal Server Error
```

Please, I need your help in resolving this.

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1):

According to your docs, **/api-2.0/courses/** uses **Basic authentication** which is a simple authentication scheme built into the HTTP protocol.

Technically it needs a header:

```
Authorization : Basic ******
```

In wich ***** is a base64 encode of **clientid:clientsecret**

Something like this:

```
var clientId = 'Test';
var clientSecret = '123';
var authHeaderValue = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(clientId + ':' + clientSecret).toString('base64');
```

And then, add to your options:

```
var options = {
    ...
    headers: {
        'Authorization': authHeaderValue
    },
    ...
  };
```

Check this for more examples:

- [How to use http.client in Node.js if there is basic authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905126/how-to-use-http-client-in-node-js-if-there-is-basic-authorization/3905553)

Comment: Thanks @JRichardsz I did the string conversion to base64 like so: 
```
const client_id = Buffer.from(CLIENT_ID).toString('base64');
const client_secret =  Buffer.from(CLIENT_SECRET).toString('base64');
const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'courses/?page=1&page_size=5',
            baseURL: API_URL,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + client_id + ':' + client_secret,
            },
            responseType: 'json',
          };
        const response = await axios(options);
```
but it's still throwing error. Any suggestion?

Comment: Try with curl and if it works, compare it with your nodejs code. Also your code is wrong. I updated the answer with a complete sample

Comment: Thanks @JRichardsz ! It's working now following your edited answer.

Comment: If this helped to solve your question, please click the checkmark on the left to mark this as solved and/or the arrow up  to mark as useful