# Trying to capture node.js http traffic with a protocol analyser (Charles) but can't get node to use proxy

Tags: http, macos, node.js, proxy, https

i'm trying to capture node.js http traffic with a protocol analyser (Charles) but can't get node to use the proxy. Is there some way to get nodes http and https modules to use a proxy?

I'm using OSX by the way

Answer (score 6):

Thanks [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59198/chris) in my case I was using Charles and [Request](https://github.com/request/request) module. There is a handle [proxy option](https://github.com/request/request#proxies) to put your charles port.

So to find your port in the Charles menu Proxy->Proxy Settings->Http Proxy

Use this port number in any request eg:

```
request.get(url, {
  'proxy': 'http://localhost:<charles-proxy-port>'
}, function (error, response, body) {
   //did you see me in Charles??
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. I was following the instructions from [How can I use an http proxy with node.js http.Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862813/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-with-node-js-http-client)
And i thought i needed to use https to access the proxy. But if i use http to access the proxy, and pass eg 'path: 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken', then it works...