# Doing http requests through a SOCKS5 proxy in NodeJS

Tags: http, node.js, proxy, tor

I'm planning to do a series of HTTP requests in NodeJS though Tor.
Tor uses SOCKS5 so I went out and searched for a way to proxify HTTP requests in NodeJS.
I'm planning to the the default http.request() function to do the work.
 However, I can't seem to find a way to use a proxy with that.
 Someone suggested that I could do this:

```
var http = require("http");
var options = {
  host: "localhost",
  port: 9050,
  path: "http://check.torproject.org",
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Host: "http://check.torproject.org",
  }
};
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});
```

But it didn't work.
So, any suggestions?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've just published two modules that should help you do this: [socks5-**http**-client](https://github.com/mattcg/socks5-http-client) and [socks5-**https**-client](https://github.com/mattcg/socks5-https-client).

Just use those instead of the default `http` module. The API is the same. For example:

```
require('socks5-http-client').request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
});
```

Comment: npm install socks5-http-client :)

Comment: any idea why it doesn't work inside a Promise? I am getting ECONNREFUSED

Comment: this gives `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1080` for some reason it's overriding my port 9050 with 1080

Answer (score 13):

I know I'm answering an old question but there is a better solution available for this question, about how to use sock4 & sock5 proxy in Node.js. For the sake of simplicity, I will be using request-promise module however you can also use bare request module.

Requrement: [socks-proxy-agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socks-proxy-agent), [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)

Example:

```
async function main() {


var proxy = "socks4://1.2.3.4:35618"

var agent = new SocksProxyAgent(proxy);

var options = {
    uri: 'http://targetUrl',
    agent: agent,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
    }
}

try {
    var responce = await rp(options)
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
}

console.log(responce)  }
```

Comment: upvoted! but how do I know if its working, i am connecting to a websocket ws module thtough this and testing some free socks proxies from here https://www.socks-proxy.net/ the thing is it seems to connect regardless of whether the port and host combination is correct or not

Comment: you can try replacing this URL https://wtfismyip.com/json in place of target URL. If the proxy is working correctly you should see proxy's IP and proxy's ISP as your own IP. I hope you got the point

Comment: Is there a way to use client certificates with this?

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but you may want to keep your eye on these two modules.

https://github.com/Ayms/node-Tor

Support is being added into: https://github.com/Ayms/node-bot.

I sent him an email asking when he expected this to be complete, will update this post soon with that information.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and used [polipo](https://www.irif.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/) as proxy between node and TOR

```
node (request) - polilp httproxy:8123 -  polipo - tor (socks5:9050).
```

For mac (osx with [brew](http://brew.sh/)) it worked like this:

```
brew install polipo tor
tor # start top
polipo socksParentProxy=localhost:9050 # start polipo
```

Working example with [request](https://github.com/request/request)

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {'url':'https://check.torproject.org/', 'proxy':'http://localhost:8123'}

request(options,
            function (error, response, body) {
            if (error){
                console.log(error);
                return;
            }

            var usingTor = (body.indexOf('Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.')  !== -1);
            expect(usingTor).to.equal(true);   

        });
```

Comment: why did someone downvote?? this is the only answer that actually works here

Answer (score 1):

If you're on *nix machine, you can use tsocks. It will "socksify" the whole process so you can use it even for anything which does not support proxies at all. This [article](https://www.redpill-linpro.com/sysadvent/2015/12/13/socks-proxy-as-poor-mans-vpn.html) has some great examples

Basically it's as easy as doing `tsocks node myscript.js`. I am not sure if it works with `tsocks npm start` but you could give it a try (npm starts your code as a subprocess)

All you need is some setup first (put `server = 127.0.0.1` to `etc/tsocks.conf`)

Comment: tsocks.conf not exists under /etc

Answer (score 0):

Yo should try with polipo, that work for me;
http://ccm.net/faq/805-installing-an-easy-http-proxy-cache-polipo

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference