# Issue with HTTP request using node through TOR

Tags: node.js, configuration, tor

I am relatively new to both node and TOR. I'm trying to send a request using a node application through TOR. Ive set up a basic app using [socks5-HTTP-client](https://github.com/mattcg/socks5-http-client). Also, TOR is installed (sudo port install tor) and I ran the server using `tor`..

Executing the app, node gives me the following error

```
Error: SOCKS connection failed. General SOCKS server failure.
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/MyName/node_modules/socks5-client/lib/Socket.js:199:12)
    at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

The TOR server reports the following to me:

```
[warn] Rejecting SOCKS request for anonymous connection to private address [scrubbed].
```

The topic I found [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/what-does-warning-rejecting-socks-request-for-anonymous-connection-to-private) does not seem to apply to this case. Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530159/doing-http-requests-through-a-socks5-proxy-in-nodejs?rq=1) earlier article does not answer my question. Neither can I find any difference between the [example](https://github.com/mattcg/socks5-http-client/blob/master/example/tor.js) given by the developer of the socks5 module and my case.

I am unsure whether this is an issue with my configuration in node or my TOR configuration.

Below is the JS code

```
var shttp = require('socks5-http-client');
var config = 
        { url: 'http://whatismyipaddress.com/', // I'd like to see a different IP on every request, that should be the end result, correct?
      socksHost: '127.0.0.1',
        socksPort: 9050
    }
shttp.get(config, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('readable', function() {
        console.log(res.read());
    });
});
```

Also, in my `torrc.sample` configuration file, I made sure the following is set up:

```
SOCKSPort 127.0.0.1:9050
```

Also, my SOCKSPolicy is set up as follows:

```
SOCKSPolicy accept 192.168.0.0/16
SOCKSPolicy accept6 FC00::/7
SOCKSPolicy reject *
```

At the time of trying, my internal IP address was 192.168.0.11, seems fine to me.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting that error because the URL isn't getting passed to the request properly so it is trying to issue a SOCKS request to `localhost` instead of the site you want to visit.

URLs are parsed using `url.parse`.

Try changing your code to:

```
var shttp = require('socks5-http-client');
var url = require('url');
var config = url.parse('http://whatismyipaddress.com/');
config.socksHost = '127.0.0.1';
config.socksPort = 9050;

shttp.get(config, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('readable', function() {
        console.log(res.read());
    });
});
```

Also, it appears `whatismyipaddress.com` might be blocking Tor as I don't get a response back from them.  Try `ipchicken.com` or some other site.  You may need to set a `User-Agent` header to get the former site to reply, but this code change does work.