# How can I use an http proxy with node.js https?

Tags: node.js, https, proxy

I want to make an https request call from node.js, using the standar https Client. But I cannot reach the remote server directly from my network and need to go through a proxy.

How do I tell node.js to use the proxy?
I tried option as following the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862813/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-with-node-js-http-client)

```
{ path : 'https://api.xxx.com:8081/token';
host : 'proxy-us.xxxx.com';
port : 8082;
method : POST_METHOD;
headers : {
    'host':  "api.xxx.com:8081"
}
```

But never reached

Comment: Is it an HTTP or SOCKS proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a big fan of [Mikeal's request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request). It makes http requests very easy and has many features such as proxy support, streaming, forms, auth and oauth signing. Here is a proxy example:

```
var request = require('request');
request({'url':'https://api.xxx.com:8081/token',
         'proxy':'http://proxy-us.xxxx.com:8082'}, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
  }
})
```

Comment: It is great for http, but I need https requeqes