# How to send node.js http request via proxy (using require('http').request method)

Tags: node.js, http, proxy, request

Probably related to [How can I use an http proxy with node.js http.Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862813/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-with-node-js-http-client)

I've read this post, and tried it here.
https://gist.github.com/lessmind/5704519

the `request` function sends a request to specify url, print the request options and page body, when it got a `proxy` param, it'll parse it and set into the request options as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862813/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-with-node-js-http-client) said.

But when I tried it on http://showip.net/, the returned ip are the same with proxy or not.

Did I make anything wrong? Or any other way to send a request via proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to
http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

`hostname: To support url.parse() hostname is preferred over host`

Should add this line when overwriting proxy informations.

```
options.hostname = proxy.hostname;
```