# Getting ETIMEDOUT error when I try to do a simple Get request?

Tags: node.js, http

Hi I am trying to call a simple web API which returns a string as response. I want to use node for this. Since I am new to node so I tried reffering to many blog post and got a code snippet which I used but I am getting same error for all urls whether its google.com or anything else.

My **Node** code is as follows

```
var http = require('http');

//The url we want is: 'www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
var options = {
  host: 'www.random.org',
  path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';

  //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();
```

**Error:**

```
F:\nodejs>node ..\NodeLearning\TestServer1\test.js

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
```

Can Any one tell me what has gone wrong here?

Comment: Works for me. Check your internet connection.

Comment: I was trying to do so in my office network ... which I think has some restriction... Its working for me on my own network.

Comment: you probably have to use a proxy server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862813/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-with-node-js-http-client

Answer (score 1):

Can you try one more time by setting a proxy like mentioned below

```
var options = {
  host: 'www.random.org',
  path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new',
  proxy:'add your proxy setting' 
};
```

Comment: Where have you typed the settings ?

Comment: No need to type settings anywhere, you can direct assign your proxy string to proxy field.