# How do I configure grunt-connect-proxy behind a firewall?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I am trying to setup `grunt-contrib-connect` to supply a proxy for my XHR calls. I found [`grunt-connect-proxy`](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy) which seems to be what I want. But I am behind a corporate firewall that does not allow the requests from `node` to pass through.

The error I get is:

`An error has occurred: {"code":"ETIMEDOUT","errno":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect"}`

How do I setup the `connect` task so that it passes through the corporate firewall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I finally found out how to do it.

```
connect : {
    server: {
        proxies: [
            {
                context: '/proxy',
                host: 'proxyhost', // e.g. someproxy.com
                port: 8080, // proxy port
                headers: {
                    Host: "example.com" // the real host you want to access
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3862813/619839) helped me figure it out, but I would have found the answer a lot faster if the question was more specific to `grunt-connect-proxy`, so I thought I'd add this.