# What could cause "connect ETIMEDOUT" error when the URL is working in browser?

Tags: node.js, http

I train myslef with NodeJS and tried a simple GET call.
Here is my code:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: 'www.boardgamegeek.com',
    path: '/xmlapi/boardgame/1?stats=1',
    method: 'GET'
}

var request = http.request(options, function (response) {
    var str = ""
    response.on('data', function (data) {
        str += data;
    });
    response.on('end', function () {
        console.log(str);
    });
});

request.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('Problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

request.end();
```

The URL called seems to work in my browser https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/1?stats=1

Anyway, I've got *Problem with request: connect ETIMEDOUT* when I run the code and I have no idea how to fix it.

What could cause this error ? Is it my code or is it a network/proxy issue?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yeah indeed, I've got a corporate proxy!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When behind a proxy you need to make the following modifications (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862813#answer-6781592)):

- put the proxy host in the `host` parameter
- put the proxy port in the `port` parameter
- put the full destination URL in the `path` parameter :

Which gives:

```
var options = {
    host: '<PROXY_HOST>',
    port: '<PROXY_PORT>',
    path: 'http://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/1?stats=1',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        Host: 'www.boardgamegeek.com'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I had to add http in the path and an host header but not it's working trough the proxy.

Comment: I have an username and a password on my proxy, how can I implement this?

Comment: What about if the code comes from a 3pp and we cannot modify it? how to bypass the proxy?

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was because of `http` but not `https` as required

Answer (score 2):

If this error occurs while using POSTMAN.

So, when you call a request in Postman and the API requires your VPN to be up before you can make a successful call. You will need to connect or reconnect your VPN.

In my case, I was working on a company's laptop. I found out it was the VPN that was down.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue on Ubuntu Server while maintaining a node instance on PM2. Basically after restarting the instance after taking the pull I was getting the same error on initial connection of mySQL inside the code.

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/home/deam_server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:419:13)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:275:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:447:8)
at ontimeout (timers.js:427:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:289:5)
at listOnTimeout (timers.js:252:5)
at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:212:10)
```

Though the same code was running perfectly on my local machine.
After that I used "df" command which helped me to realise that my root directory was 100% occupied. I allotted some memory to the root directory and the restarted the node instance and then it started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The following change with the request worked for me:

```
 var options = {
         proxy:'PROXY URL', 
         uri: 'API URL',
         method: 'GET' 
         }
 request(options, function (err, response, body) {
     if(err){
        console.log('error:', err);
       } else {
     console.log('body:', body);
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a misconfigured subnet. Only one of the 2 subnets in the ELB worked. But my client kept trying to connect to the misconfigured one.

Answer (score 1):

if you have URL
like :

```
  URL: 'localhost:3030/integration',
```

The URL above cause some issues because HTTP does not exist at the beginning of URL so Just change it to it should work.

```
URL: 'http://localhost:3030/integration',
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was getting this error because the request body of my post api was very large.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can simply be because your internet is down.

Answer (score 0):

A reason that I encountered was that the TLS certificate on the server was not valid, for the https request that I was making.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in organizations please get access to the port you are using eg:8000