# "Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established", node 10

Tags: node.js, ssl, vpn

When I send request to google api (using either axios or just https), e.g. `https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953?key=...`

I always hit the "**Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established**" error.

But if I send request to https://api.github.com, it works just fine. I have googled the error, but I can't find much useful information.  Here https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21088 said if the server uses TLS 1.0, it may happen but apparently it is not my case.

I also try [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) but still hit the same error.

Any idea how to fix the error ?

---- update ----

My question was closed 5 months ago. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1471) against googleapi and it was also closed. I had gave it up but to my surprise it keeps getting traffic. So I updated my question and hope it will be reopened.

First, google api has moved to here https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client

Second, just using vpn to run [the first example](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#first-example) there (using vpn because google service is blocked for whatever reason), I will get connect ETIMEDOUT while I can get the result from browser.

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const blogger = google.blogger({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: 'YOUR API KEY'
});

blogger.blogs.get({blogId: '3213900'}, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(`The blog url is ${res.data.url}`);
});
//But I can get result in browser https://blogger.googleapis.com/v3/blogs/3213900?key=xxx
```

I think the problem was solvable because nodejs doesn't send the request through my vpn proxy. So my question is somewhat related to this one, [What could cause "connect ETIMEDOUT" error when the URL is working in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33350604/what-could-cause-connect-etimedout-error-when-the-url-is-working-in-browser)

But the solution there did not work for me. One answer in this  SO [How can I use an http proxy with node.js http.Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862813/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-with-node-js-http-client) mentioned using [request](https://github.com/request/request) and it works!

```
var request = require("request");

request(
  {
    url:
      "https://blogger.googleapis.com/v3/blogs/3213900?key=xxx",
    method: "GET",
    proxy: my-vpn-proxy,
  },
  function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(body);
    }
  }
);
```

Too bad request was deprecated! I can't make axios works too!

I also tried [tunnel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel) and got `read ECONNRESET error`; I tried [global-tunnel-ng](https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-tunnel-ng) and got the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'proxy' of undefined
```

But [https-proxy-agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/https-proxy-agent) works too,

```
var url = require('url');
var https = require('https');
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
 
// HTTP/HTTPS proxy to connect to
var proxy = 'my-vpn-proxy';

var endpoint = 'https://blogger.googleapis.com/v3/blogs/3213900?key=xxx';
var opts = url.parse(endpoint);
 
var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxy);
opts.agent = agent;
 
https.get(opts, function (res) {
  console.log('"response" event!', res.headers);
  res.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

So I think this problem may be solvable.

Comment: Proxy or firewall blocking the request? Do you get a similar error when opening `https://www.googleapis.com` in a browser?

Comment: Oh right. I am using vpn but I can get the correct result if open that link in chrome

Comment: Code? Log? Information that would help anybody solve the problem?

Comment: ```https://www.googleapis.com``` Yes I also having opening this on browser

Comment: `https://www.googleapis.com` it gives not found

I stuck on a problem with firebase storage: 

`message: 'request to https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/res/o?uploadType=multipart&name=61928166801.png failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established',
>    type: 'system',
>    errno: 'ECONNRESET',
>    code: 'ECONNRESET'
>  }`

Comment: googleapis it also gives me not found, any one solve this issue?

Comment: Is this a real error message? Where did it come from? Or is this just some application text of your own devising? Why would the *client* socket disconnect? Surely it wa the *server* that disconnected?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne all the error messages I listed here was real. I didn't make  it up. I remembered very clearly I hit "Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established" error at first and searching for  a solution for a long time. Like I said I opened the question in 2018 and it was closed 5 months ago. So I had gave it up. But to my surprise people keep hitting it so I updated my question and it was re-opened. You can also check my 2 github issues.

Comment: For me Windows Chrome `https://www.googleapis.com/` returns `404 Not Found`

Comment: @BaltoStar I think it is because, as I said in my update, google api has moved to github

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the question was re-opened I raised [another issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/2345) against google api and finally got the answer!

So google api has supported using proxy, [check here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#using-a-proxy)

Answer (score 6):

In case, someone else faces this same problem, a possible solution (if you are using windows OS), is to follow the process below:

- Press the Windows Key
- Search For Internet Options
- Click on "Internet Options"
- Click On "Connection"
- Go to LAN Settings
- Uncheck "Use Proxy Server for LAN ...."

It should work but the permanent solution is to make sure you turn all software that might be automatically setting up proxy for you.

Answer (score 3):

This error could be related to your proxy.  If on Unix, check your HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables.

Comment: I am using Windows OS. The same solution works. By fixing these two variables, my issue is gone. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should mention how to check these variables.

Comment: @KevinH, in python, `import os; os.environ["https_proxy"]`. This will raise an error if you have not set it yet. If had, in the CMD enter `set https_proxy=` to remove the value.

Answer (score 3):

If you run `npm/yarn install` from a terminal, temporarily cancel the proxy configuration:

`unset https_proxy && unset http_proxy`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was caused by wrong Node version. Had to run `nvm use` because it was a different project using version **16**, while I was using **14** in previous project.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful fix is maybe you forgot to add your IP address try adding your IP address from the network access tab