# aws lambda error due to Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: node.js, ssl, promise, amazon-cognito

The error appear to originated from  `cognito-express` npm but The code is not using cognito at that point at all.
What could be root cause?

```
2020-11-01T10:34:16.482Z    7fc3f543-6bc1-43f5-a2df-afcee90c8ff5    ERROR   (node:8) [DEP0097] DeprecationWarning: Using a domain property in MakeCallback is deprecated. Use the async_context variant of MakeCallback or the AsyncResource class instead.
```

```
2020-11-01T10:34:16.496Z    7fc3f543-6bc1-43f5-a2df-afcee90c8ff5    ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "TypeError: Unable to generate certificate due to \nRequestError: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established",
    "reason": {
        "errorType": "TypeError",
        "errorMessage": "Unable to generate certificate due to \nRequestError: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established",
        "stack": [
            "TypeError: Unable to generate certificate due to ",
            "RequestError: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established",
            "    at /var/task/node_modules/cognito-express/lib/strategy.js:42:23",
            "    at bound (domain.js:427:14)",
            "    at runBound (domain.js:440:12)",
            "    at tryCatcher (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)",
            "    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)",
            "    at Promise._settlePromise (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)",
            "    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)",
            "    at Promise._settlePromises (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:725:18)",
            "    at _drainQueueStep (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)",
            "    at _drainQueue (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)",
            "    at Async._drainQueues (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)",
            "    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)",
            "    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)",
            "    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:138:15)",
            "    at process.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:118:14)"
        ]
    },
    "promise": {
        "isFulfilled": false,
        "isRejected": true,
        "rejectionReason": {
            "errorType": "TypeError",
            "errorMessage": "Unable to generate certificate due to \nRequestError: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established",
            "stack": [
                "TypeError: Unable to generate certificate due to ",
                "RequestError: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established",
                "    at /var/task/node_modules/cognito-express/lib/strategy.js:42:23",
                "    at bound (domain.js:427:14)",
                "    at runBound (domain.js:440:12)",
                "    at tryCatcher (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)",
                "    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)",
                "    at Promise._settlePromise (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)",
                "    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)",
                "    at Promise._settlePromises (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:725:18)",
                "    at _drainQueueStep (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)",
                "    at _drainQueue (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)",
                "    at Async._drainQueues (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)",
                "    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)",
                "    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)",
                "    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:138:15)",
                "    at process.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:118:14)"
            ]
        }
    },
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: TypeError: Unable to generate certificate due to ",
        "RequestError: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established",
        "    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)",
        "    at process.emit (events.js:327:22)",
        "    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)",
        "    at eventToObjectGenerator.promiseCreated (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:258:33)",
        "    at activeFireEvent (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:301:44)",
        "    at fireRejectionEvent (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:703:14)",
        "    at Promise._notifyUnhandledRejection (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:90:9)",
        "    at Timeout.unhandledRejectionCheck [as _onTimeout] (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:39:25)",
        "    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)",
        "    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)"
    ]
}

2020-11-01T10:34:16.496Z 7fc3f543-6bc1-43f5-a2df-afcee90c8ff5 ERROR Unhandled Promise Rejection {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"TypeError: Unable to generate certificate due to \nRequestError: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established","reason":{"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"Unable to generate certificate due to \nRequestError: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established","stack":["TypeError: Unable to generate certificate due to ","RequestError: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established"," at /var/task/node_modules/cognito-express/lib/strategy.js:42:23"," at bound (domain.js:427:14)"," at runBound (domain.js:440:12)"," at tryCatcher (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)"," at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)"," at Promise._settlePromise (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)"," at Promise._settlePromise0 (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)"," at Promise._settlePromises (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:725:18)"," at _drainQueueStep (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)"," at _drainQueue (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)"," at Async._drainQueues (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)"," at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)"," at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)"," at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:138:15)"," at process.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:118:14)"]},"promise":{"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":true,"rejectionReason":{"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"Unable to generate certificate due to \nRequestError: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established","stack":["TypeError: Unable to generate certificate due to ","RequestError: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established"," at /var/task/node_modules/cognito-express/lib/strategy.js:42:23"," at bound (domain.js:427:14)"," at runBound (domain.js:440:12)"," at tryCatcher (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)"," at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)"," at Promise._settlePromise (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)"," at Promise._settlePromise0 (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)"," at Promise._settlePromises (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:725:18)"," at _drainQueueStep (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)"," at _drainQueue (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)"," at Async._drainQueues (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)"," at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)"," at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)"," at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:138:15)"," at process.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:118:14)"]}},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: TypeError: Unable to generate certificate due to ","RequestError: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established"," at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)"," at process.emit (events.js:327:22)"," at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)"," at eventToObjectGenerator.promiseCreated (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:258:33)"," at activeFireEvent (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:301:44)"," at fireRejectionEvent (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:703:14)"," at Promise._notifyUnhandledRejection (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:90:9)"," at Timeout.unhandledRejectionCheck [as _onTimeout] (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:39:25)"," at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)"," at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)"]}
```

This has happened in multiple endpoints

Comment: If it says it originates from there then it rather does ;) It may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53593182/client-network-socket-disconnected-before-secure-tls-connection-was-established. It looks as if the issue might be somewhere inside the `request` library and since `congnito-express` relies on it...