# Discord.JS TLS errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have been working on a bot for some time now. Since I updated it to v15.5.0, after a while it works fine, does exactly what I want but then crashes, giving the following error. This seems to be a TLS issue.

```
Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:631:14)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (node:_tls_wrap:1565:19)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:388:22)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1305:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21)
```

The source code for the bot is [here](https://github.com/Apollyon094/ApollyonBot)

Will I have to downgrade? If so, to what version of node?

I'm using this on a Windows 10 64bit computer with no proxy settings whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Node.js v15, but it seems like it is an issue on your end (with your connection, or your computer). [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53593182/client-network-socket-disconnected-before-secure-tls-connection-was-established) may help you to resolve your issue.