# ADO Pipelines Encountering Errors while installing NuGet on a self hosted build server

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, nuget, azure-pipelines

I'm configuring an ADO Build Pipeline, however, it's failing on the Install NuGet step

YAML

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: TestPool

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
```

I got the following error

`You are using a query match on the version string. Behavior changes or breaking changes might occur as NuGet updates to a new version. ERR:Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established`

Comment: what type of OS is in the TestPool?

Comment: Windows Server 2019 (Cloud edition)

Answer (score 0):

According to the YAML and error message, it seems that you are using self-hosted
agent and the error related to the TLS.

Since more and more Microsoft products/services are deprecating TLS 1.0 and 1.1, you need to ensure your applications to be working well using [TLS 1.2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/deprecating-weak-cryptographic-standards-tls-1-0-and-1-1-in-azure-devops-services/#how-to-enable-tls-1-2).

You could use the following script to check if the TLS is ok.

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri status.dev.azure.com).StatusDescription
```

If it does not OK, you need to enable the TLS 1.2 in your self-hosted agent.

And try to use the specific nuget version.

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.x
    checkLatest: true
```

Comment: tls 1.0 -1.1 are disabled tls 1.2 is supported (Client & Server) I tried updating the Yaml as you suggested am still getting the same error

Comment: Have you check if the tls is 1.2? (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri status.dev.azure.com).StatusDescription it should be return ok

Comment: Yes though had to add the -UseBasicParsing parameter

Comment: please check the proxy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53593182/client-network-socket-disconnected-before-secure-tls-connection-was-established