# Error: connect ETIMEDOUT, how to solve it? using Node.js and MySQL2

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-workbench, web-deployment

I used Node.js and MySQL2. Working on MySQL workbench. Created virtual DB using Railway workbench. Schemas and tables are created. But showing `ETIMEDOUT error in the VS code's terminal when i try to run node index.js. What can i do?

**db.js**:

```js
import mysql2 from 'mysql2';
    
export const db = mysql2.createConnection({
    host: 'containers-us-west-174.railway.app',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'railway'
})
```

**index.js**:

```js
import express from 'express';
import authRoutes from './routes/auth.js';
import userRoutes from './routes/users.js';
import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import multer from 'multer';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '../client/public/upload');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
    }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

app.post('/api/upload', upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {
    const file = req.file;
    res.status(200).json(file?.filename)
});


app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/api/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/api/posts', postRoutes);


app.listen(8800, () => {
    console.log('Connected wih backend!');
})
```

In my VS Code Terminal it is showing this **error**:

```
Connected wih backend!
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleTimeoutError (I:\EMON\Web-Development\FINALE\timeless-blog-f\api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:189:17)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._notifyError (I:\EMON\Web-Development\FINALE\timeless-blog-f\api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:236:12)
    at Connection._handleFatalError (I:\EMON\Web-Development\FINALE\timeless-blog-f\api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:167:10)
    at Connection._handleNetworkError (I:\EMON\Web-Development\FINALE\timeless-blog-f\api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:180:10)
    at Connection._handleTimeoutError (I:\EMON\Web-Development\FINALE\timeless-blog-f\api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:193:10)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true
}
```

I was trying to deploting in railway. I'm using MySQL workbench.

In Railway deployment logs this **error** shows:

```
> api@1.0.0 start
> node index.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1239
return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
^
Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1239:18)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12) {
code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
```

And deployment crashed!

Any solution?

Comment: The error is probably related to the `bcrypt`, follow this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809611/bcrypt-invalid-elf-header-when-running-node-app

Comment: You may find this URL has clues to a solution for you. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33350604/what-could-cause-connect-etimedout-error-when-the-url-is-working-in-browser