# Unable to see http traffic from/to my NodeJS app in Charles [mac]

Tags: macos, charles-proxy

I am running Charles to inspect HTTP traffic between a node js client and a service running locally on my machine (a Mac). I am able to access the service but don't see any trace in Charles. I have tried replacing localhost with my machine's IP name but still no trace. If I type the service URL in Chrome I do see a trace. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Here is my nodejs code:

```
var thrift = require('thrift'); // I use Apache Thrift
var myService = require('./gen-nodejs/MyService'); // this is code generated by thrift compiler
var transport = thrift.TBufferedTransport();
var protocol = thrift.TBinaryProtocol();
var connection = thrift.createHttpConnection("localhost", 5331, {
  transport : transport,
  protocol : protocol,
  path: '/myhandler',
});

connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

// Create a client with the connection
var client = thrift.createHttpClient(myService, connection);
console.log('calling getTotalJobCount...');

client.getTotalJobCount(function(count)
{
    console.log('total job count = ' + count);
});
```

and my proxy settings:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed this myself with help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862813/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-with-node-js-http-client) link. Charles intercepts the traffic crossing the system proxy which is `127.0.0.1:8888` on my mac. Here is proper code:

```
// give path to the proxy in argument to createHttpConnection
var connection = thrift.createHttpConnection('127.0.0.1', 8888, {
  transport : transport,
  protocol : protocol,
  path: 'http://localhost:5331/myhandler', // give the actual URL you want to connect to here
});
```

In addition need to use `thrift.TBufferedTransport` instead of `thrift.TBufferedTransport()` and `thrift.TBinaryProtocol` instead of `thrift.TBinaryProtocol()`