# intercept network request using fiddler in sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ubuntu-14.04, fiddler

I've a sails.js app which makes api request in third party (for an example marketo api) to get data.

Is there any way that I can set a proxy in sails.js so that I can see all the request made by [sail.js](http://sailsjs.com/) app into the [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

By the way my os is **ubuntu 14.04** and I'm using **mono** to run fiddler

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are making your API requests.

If you are using [request](http://github.com/request/request), you can set the proxy details this way:

```
let request = require('request');
// using default fiddler port
let proxiedRequest = request.defaults({'proxy': 'http://127.0.0.1:8888'});

proxiedRequest.get("http://api.example.com/foo", function (err, resp, body) {
  ...
})
```

If you are using the node http client, check "[How can I use an http proxy with node.js http.Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6781592/3058802)"

Comment: @gnus Actually I've no control on how the request has been made because I use third party library for multiple vendor. suppose for marketo I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-marketo-rest so it may vary from library to library. So, I need generic solution which will work regardless how those libraries interact with third party.