# How can I send HTTP requests with vanilla Node that will get picked up by Fiddler?

Tags: node.js, https, fiddler

I want to send HTTPS POST requests through Node using the `https` module, and I want to capture them with Fiddler. How can I do this? I've found a few pieces of sample code, but they all use other modules like the `requests` library.

Comment: The very same way as with http, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862813/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-with-node-js-http-client . Node doesn't have to be aware of Fiddler. It just need to send requests through its proxy, with `https`, or `request`, or anything else.

Comment: @estus That answer doesn't seem to work. The intended usage of the options seems to be for `host` to be `example.com` and for `path` to be `pages/example.html`, say. You can't put the entire URL in the `path` and stick the proxy in `host`. I get a ECONNREFUSED error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that I had used. You will need to require the https module from node.
create a options obj like below.

```
options = {
    host: 'host',
    path: 'uri',
    port: 'port',
    method:'POST',
    headers: {'headerName':value}};
   }
```

create a request object

```
  var call = https.request(options, callback); 
  call.write(payload);
  call.end();
```

payload is your post data, the callback function is executed once the https call is complete.

Comment: What should the values of host, path, and port be?

Comment: that is location of the service you want to submit your HTTP/S post to.

Comment: So then where do you specify the address and port of Fiddler's proxy? Are you sure you've understood the question?

Comment: If I understood correct - you mean fiddler - HTTP debugging proxy server application - this should be able to pick up the traffic from your app when you make the outbound call.  - and setup the fiddler proxy detail at node level -  Try this https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/use-fiddler-with-node-js