# Request with a proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am sending a GET request using a proxy. If I do not set tunneling to false I get an error as shown below:

> *Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect EINVAL 0.0.159.213:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)*

If I set `tunnel = false`, I get the following error:

> *Invalid protocol: 188.168.58.130:*

Code:

```
 const request = require('request');
 request({
   method: 'GET',
   url,
   proxy: "188.168.58.130:40917",
   tunnel: false
 }, (err, res, body) => { ... })
```

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21281075/4664094

Comment: adding http:// worked. Though I am getting new error now:

Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop.

You can add this an answer, i'll accept.

Comment: I'll just mark it as a duplicate, you can accept that manually and it'll redirect the question :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use an http proxy with node.js http.Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862813/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-with-node-js-http-client)