# run node behind proxy

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have a simple code to detect the aws account id and check if it matches the id in a json file

```
$ cat sample.json

{
  "account_id": "123456789012",
  "name": "foo"
}
```

the nodejs code

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const sts = new aws.STS();

const file = 'sample.json';
const content = fs.readFileSync(file);
const jsonContent = JSON.parse(content);

sts.getCallerIdentity({}, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('can not get aws account id');
    process.exit(-1);
  } else if (data.Account !== jsonContent.account_id) {
    console.log(util.format('aws account id does not match its configuration file %s , exist ...', file));
    process.exit(-1);
  } else {
    console.log('account matched');
  }
});
```

If I run it directly on my laptop, it works, show "account matched"

But when I run in docker with corporate proxy (`I can curl public url in docker, so the proxy setting is no issue here`), it is failed with error

```
can not get aws account id

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 255
npm ERR! sample@1.0.0 account: `node a.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 255
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sample@1.0.0 account script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-05-08T05_45_56_807Z-debug.log
```

No useful information in `/root/.npm/_logs/2019-05-08T05_45_56_807Z-debug.log`

I can `curl` public url in the running container.

```
bash-4.3# curl www.google.com|more
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   676    0   676    0     0   3907      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3885
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en-AU"><head><meta content="text/
...
```

So I guess it is because the proxy blocked the access. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: i found this url (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862813/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-with-node-js-http-client), but not sure how to use with `aws-sdk`, any hints for me?

Comment: Seems this is the solution provided by aws (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-configuring-proxies.html) but I still can't make it work